# Issue with Laravel and Lists

Tags: laravel

I am trying to create a list with concat values, my code is:

```
\App\Models\Clientes::selectRaw( 
        " CONCAT('numero', ' ', 'razon_social') as nombre, id " 
        )->lists('nombre', 'id')->all();
```

My HTML code is:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
{!! Form::label('cliente', 'Cliente') !!}
{!! Form::select('cliente', 
    ($clientes), 
    null,
    ['class' => 'form-control dropdown_add',
                'required',
                'placeholder' => 'Cliente...']) 
!!}
```

Why does it show me in the select field this value:

`numero razon_social`

Why does it not show me like this: `789 Bombillos C.A`?

I mean it is showing me the name of the column of the table but it is not showing me the value.

Thanks

Comment: Re-write your question well

Comment: Try it like this: " CONCAT(numero, ' ', razon_social) as nombre, id "

Comment: what version of laravel are you using? lists is depricated from laravel 5.2

Comment: Thanks @AlbertoGuilherme it worked!! :D

Comment: @InversionesCovaCodesCA No problem, I posted a answer so you can mark as the correct one.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the quotes on the filds names `numero` and `razon_social`

```
\App\Models\Clientes::selectRaw( " CONCAT('numero', ' ', 'razon_social') as nombre, id " )->lists('nombre', 'id')->all();
```

You need to use them like this:

```
\App\Models\Clientes::selectRaw( " CONCAT(numero, ' ', razon_social) as nombre, id " )->lists('nombre', 'id')->all();
```